# Visual Studio 2017 Git extension counting fetching others' work as a merge to same branch

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017

A friend and I are simultaneously working on a Github repository. We both are using Visual Studio 2017 with the Git extension installed and both have write access to the repository.

If I push a commit to the repository and he syncs it, his next push will contain an extra merge commit that contained the prior work that I fetched. If I fetch something he has pushed and later push a commit, the same thing happens.

[Here is an example of a resulting merge](https://github.com/Wildenhaus/xenia/commit/5bb97351818d910ce88275d29a62573f578384fb) that was caused after I received his changes and pushed code to the repository.

Why is this happening, and how can we avoid this from happening every time we push code to the repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the default when syncing with visual Studio is to do a normal 'pull' i.e. with a merge.

You could :

- use another tool that permit to better understand and master git giving you all the git power, for example [Git Extensions](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions).
- set the git settings to do a rebase instead of a merge by default:

  `git config --global pull.rebase true`

Answer (score 1):

You could also set this in Visual Studio itself

In the team Explorer, Go to Settings, then "global settings":

[image]

and enable "Rebase local branch when pulling"

[image]